# Creating a rule-based list of lists using Manipulate[...]

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, code-request

Given a list of lists:

```
list = {{x1, x2, x3}, {y1, y2, y3}, {z1, z2, z3}};
```

Some self-explanatory lists which I like to create using `Manipulate[]`:

```
(*picking the 1st elements from `x` abd `y` tuples and all elements of `z`*)
M11a = {
         {x1, y1, z1},
         {x1, y1, z2},
         {x1, y1, z3}
       }; 

(*picking the 1st and 2nd elements from `x` and `z` tuples and all elements of `y`*)
M1a2 = {
         {x1, y1, z2},
         {x1, y2, z2}, 
         {x1, y3, z2}
        };

(*picking the 3rd and 2nd elements from `x` and `z` tuples and all elements of `y`*)
M3a2 = {
         {x3, y1, z2},
         {x3, y2, z2},
         {x3, y3, z2}
        };
```

I like to create `Manipulate[]` to automatically generate the above matrices with three controls. For example, when the values of 1st and 3rd controls (x and z, respectively) are fixed, the other control for y should take all the values in `{y1, y2, y3}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Manipulate[MatrixForm @
 Tuples[Range[3] /. i_Integer :> If[MemberQ[fixed, i], {xl, yl, zl}[[{i}]], list[[i]]]],
 {{fixed, {1, 3}}, Range@3, TogglerBar}, 
 {xl, list[[1]], Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled", Enabled -> MemberQ[fixed, 1]},
 {yl, list[[2]], Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled", Enabled -> MemberQ[fixed, 2]},
 {zl, list[[3]], Slider, Appearance -> "Labeled", Enabled -> MemberQ[fixed, 3]}]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]